# Can I Limit Number of Record to be loaded from file in Hive

Tags: java, hive, bigdata

Can I Use Limit Clause in Hive Load Command

> load data local inpath '" + filepath + "' into table " + tableName Limit 1000;

Comment: Try it and you will find out ;-)

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. Load the data into your table and then simply `SELECT * from table LIMIT 1000`

Answer (score 0):

You can load first 1000 records into hive by using sqoop if source file was in RDBMS.